# Mesh Wifi v. WiFi Extenders

Tags: wireless-router, wifi-configuration

Why are Mesh WiFi systems faster than WiFi extenders?  I'm contemplating getting Google Nest's $300 system (one main router and two nodes) or getting Linksys's $50 extenders.  Aren't the nodes in a Mesh Wifi system just a bunch of extenders themselves?

Comment: Not certain, hence not an answer, but the inter-node links could be operating on different radio protocols and hence the "mesh" may be sidestepping compatibility with WiFi in order to achieve a higher speed. Extenders would be using WiFi itself in order to communicate and so effectively use twice the WiFi bandwidth (once in and once out) to do a task while if you operate on a different radio protocol on a different frequency set then you are not limiting the WiFi bandwidth itself.

Comment: What research have you done? There's a decent amount of information out there about these two different types of systems and how they operate, and I'd imagine there are explanations of exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to some extent they are 'just extenders', but they usually have additional functionality & utility, and most have a major advantage; whereas an extender usually exposes an additional SSID on an additional IP, MESH wifi makes this seamless - you will only see one SSID no matter where you are in the coverage area and you will be automatically handed-off from device to device as you move around.

I've used apowerline Netgear extender, several wifi Netgear extenders and an TP-Link wifi extender, but now have a TP-Link M9 2-device MESH. The MESH has been easier to administer, is far more reliable in terms of stable connections, and seems to offer better range. Some of this is likely simply due to the MESH being newer tech, but some of it is clearly because if the MESH being able to dynamically manage your connection in the background.

YMMV.

Comment: Ah, that really clarifies it for me.  Certainly explains the price difference.  Thank you so much @CJM.